# JavaScript dependent drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

How do you make a dependent drop down list with JavaScript?

I need first category list to trigger other 2 (or more) categories to show up with lists that depends on what was your selection on first category.

Is that possible?

Here's my code :

```
<code> 

function dropdownlist(listindex)
 {

document.formname.category2.options.length = 0;
 switch (listindex)
 {

 case "Home Ware" :
 document.formname.category2.options[0]=new Option("Select Category2","");
 document.formname.category2.options[1]=new Option("Air-Conditioners/Coolers","Air-Conditioners/Coolers");
 document.formname.category2.options[2]=new Option("Audio/Video","Audio/Video");
 document.formname.category2.options[3]=new Option("Beddings","Beddings");
 document.formname.category2.options[4]=new Option("Camera","Camera");
 document.formname.category2.options[5]=new Option("Cell Phones","Cell Phones");

 break;

 case "Education" :
 document.formname.category2.options[0]=new Option("Select Category2","");
 document.formname.category2.options[1]=new Option("Colleges","Colleges");
 document.formname.category2.options[2]=new Option("Institutes","Institutes");
 document.formname.category2.options[3]=new Option("Schools","Schools");
 document.formname.category2.options[4]=new Option("Tuitions","Tuitions");
 document.formname.category2.options[5]=new Option("Universities","Universities");

 break;

 case "Books" :
 document.formname.category2.options[0]=new Option("Select Category2","");
 document.formname.category2.options[1]=new Option("College Books","College Books");
 document.formname.category2.options[2]=new Option("Engineering","Engineering");
 document.formname.category2.options[3]=new Option("Magazines","Magazines");
 document.formname.category2.options[4]=new Option("Medicine","Medicine");
 document.formname.category2.options[5]=new Option("References","References");

 break;

 }
 return true;
 }
</code>
```

Html :

```
    <form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
 <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
 <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category1 :</td>
 <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="category1" id="category1" onchange="javascript: dropdownlist(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
 <option value="">Select Category1</option>
 <option value="Home Ware">Home Ware</option>
 <option value="Education">Education</option>
 <option value="Books">Books</option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right" valign="middle">Category2 :
 </td>
 <td align="left" valign="middle"><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 document.write('<select name="category2"><option value="">Select Category2</option></select>')
 </script>
 <noscript><select name="category2" id="category2" >
 <option value="">Select Category2</option>
 </select>
 </noscript></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

</form>
```

I believe it is not possible to create a third list that would be triggered by choosing "Home ware" and have different selections?

Comment: Sure it is possible. Provide us what have you done so far...

Comment: Javascript makes all possible :D - EX. http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/

Comment: Frogmouth, is it possible that it will show 2 subcategories?

Comment: @Frogmouth TIL. You just tought me a new trick.. I didn't realise that was possible too with the individual elements in a drop down list.  Thank you for that ;-)

Comment: @dummie ... you can do all. What you need?

Comment: @Michael Dibbets... Glad to have helped

Comment: @Frogmouth... To be more precise, im working on a computer builder, you pick Motherboard(category1) and script shows you what GPU(category2), CPU(category3) etc. are compatible with that Motherboard. Am i going the right way?

Comment: @dummie ... YES, you can: http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/10/ - BUT with a lot of `motherboard` and `components` for each, you need a different implementation based on `JSON` request.

Answer (score 7):

### UPDATE 03/2018

I review this solution because an OP (thx @stavasknall) told me that my solution doesn't work in Safari.

#### The issue:

In some browser (like Safari) the `<option>` inside a `<select>` can't be hided via CSS, if you set (in css or via Jquery) `style="display:none"` Safari simply ignores it.

#### My new solution

To target the OP goal is necessary to manipulate the DOM to change the `<option>` inside e selection, to do this there are a lot of solution i follow this one:

### HTML

```
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category1 :</td>
    <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
      <select name="category1" id="category1">
        <option value="">Select Category1</option>
        <option value="home_ware">Home Ware</option>
        <option value="education">Education</option>
        <option value="books">Books</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle">Category2 :</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
      <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category2" name="category2">
        <option value>Select Category2</option>
        <!-- Home Ware -->
        <optgroup data-rel="home_ware">
          <option value="air-conditioners_coolers">Air-Conditioners/Coolers</option>
          <option value="audio-video">Audio/Video</option>
          <option value="beddings">Beddings</option>
          <option value="camera">Camera</option>
          <option value="cell-phones">Cell Phones</option>
        </optgroup>
        <!-- Education -->
        <optgroup data-rel="education">
          <option value="Colleges">Colleges</option>
          <option value="Institutes">Institutes</option>
          <option value="Schools">Schools</option>
          <option value="Tuitions">Tuitions</option>
          <option value="Universities">Universities</option>
        </optgroup>
        <!-- Books -->
        <optgroup data-rel="books">
          <option value="College Books">College Books</option>
          <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
          <option value="Magazines">Magazines</option>
          <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
          <option value="References">References</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle">Category3 :</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
      <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category3" name="category3">
        <option value>Select Category3</option>
        <!-- Home Ware -->
        <optgroup data-rel="home_ware">
          <option value="foo1">category3 home ware 1</option>
          <option value="foo2">category3 home ware 2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <!-- Education -->
        <optgroup data-rel="education">
          <option value="foo3">category3 Education 1</option>
          <option value="foo4">category3 Education 2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <!-- Books -->
        <optgroup data-rel="books">
          <option value="foo5">category3 Books 1</option>
          <option value="foo6">category3 Books 2</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Javascript

```
var $cat = $("#category1"),
    $subcat = $(".subcat");

var optgroups = {};

$subcat.each(function(i,v){
  var $e = $(v);
  var _id = $e.attr("id");
  optgroups[_id] = {};
  $e.find("optgroup").each(function(){
    var _r = $(this).data("rel");
    $(this).find("option").addClass("is-dyn");
    optgroups[_id][_r] = $(this).html();
  });
});
$subcat.find("optgroup").remove();

var _lastRel;
$cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    if(_lastRel === _rel) return true;
    _lastRel = _rel;
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat.val("");
    $subcat.find(".is-dyn").remove();
    if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat.each(function(){
      var $el = $(this);
      var _id = $el.attr("id");
      $el.append(optgroups[_id][_rel]);
    });
    $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
});
```

In this the script save the s html inside a Javascript object (based on `<select>` `ID` and `<optgroup>` `data-rel`) and remove them from the DOM. With this solution when a `<select>` change the script find the related option and print it in the relative `<select>`.

Like in other solution also in this one you must include jQuery and you have to wrap the Javascript inside `DOMready listener` or at the end of the `<body>`.

### Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/595

---

### ORIGINAL SOLUTION

#### (non CROSS BROWSER - not work with webkit)

I change your `HTML`, `JS`, `CSS` to prevent the excessive use of Javascript.

1. First: Consider to use `jQuery` (a simple JS library that help you to create complex thing)
2. **Not create/remvoe DOM element** every time you need to change your HTML - instead HIDE this element and show all you nedd.

### HTML

```
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category1 :</td>
      <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="category1" id="category1">
          <option value="">Select Category1</option>
          <option value="home_ware">Home Ware</option>
          <option value="education">Education</option>
          <option value="books">Books</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="middle">Category2 :</td>
      <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
          <option class="label" value>Select Category2</option>
          <!-- Home Ware -->
          <option rel="home_ware" value="air-conditioners_coolers">Air-Conditioners/Coolers</option>
          <option rel="home_ware" value="audio-video">Audio/Video</option>
          <option rel="home_ware" value="beddings">Beddings</option>
          <option rel="home_ware" value="camera">Camera</option>
          <option rel="home_ware" value="cell-phones">Cell Phones</option>
          <!-- Education -->
          <option rel="education" value="Colleges">Colleges</option>
          <option rel="education" value="Institutes">Institutes</option>
          <option rel="education" value="Schools">Schools</option>
          <option rel="education" value="Tuitions">Tuitions</option>
          <option rel="education" value="Universities">Universities</option>
          <!-- Books -->
          <option rel="books" value="College Books">College Books</option>
          <option rel="books" value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
          <option rel="books" value="Magazines">Magazines</option>
          <option rel="books" value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
          <option rel="books" value="References">References</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

take a look: I use `rel` attribute to link category and sub category (to lowercase and without space or special Char):

```
<option rel="home_ware" value="">Select Category1</option>
```

### CSS

```
#category2 option{
    display:none;
}

#category2 option.label{
    display:block;
}
```

this CSS hide the subcategory options (not label) that show only if the main category is seleceted.

### JS (jQuery)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script
<script>
$(function(){

//fisrt I store in 2 var the reference of two <select>

var $cat = $("#category1"),
$subcat = $("#category2");

//this is the same thing if you write in your HTML onChange="" in first <select>

$cat.on("change",function(){

//store the value of first select every time it change
var _rel = $(this).val();

//clean the second select (value and option active) to prevent bad link (cat1 with subcat of cat2)
$subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
$subcat.val("");

//if no option is selected i disable the second select
if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);

//if a option si selected i show the option linked by rel attr
$subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
$subcat.prop("disabled",false);
});

});
</script>
```

I use jQuery because is simple, clean, and you write less code.
Take a look to jQuery's Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/. If you never use it, you should.

This resurce is needed

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

### Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/5/

### Edit

If you need to enable multiple `<select>` after you check one option of `category1` you simply change the selector of the variable `$subcat` to select more than one `<select>`.

#### HTML

add class `.subcat` to all `<select>` you need to enable when select `category1`:

```
<select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
```

becomes:

```
<select disabled="disabled" id="category2" class="subcat" name="category2">
```

Now, add the new `<select>` to your code:

```
<select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category3" name="category3">
<option value>Select Category3</option>
<!-- Home Ware -->
<option rel="home_ware" value="foo1">category3 home ware 1</option>
    <option rel="home_ware" value="foo2">category3 home ware 2</option>
<!-- Education -->
<option rel="Education" value="foo3">category3 Education 1</option>
<option rel="Education" value="foo4">category3 Education 2</option>

<!-- Books -->
<option rel="Books" value="foo5">category3 Books 1</option>
<option rel="Books" value="foo6">category3 Books 2</option>
```

**NOTE:** `<option>` have already `rel`

#### Javascript

`$subcat = $("#category2");` becomes `$subcat = $(".subcat");`

#### CSS

```
.subcat option{
    display:none;
}

.subcat option.label{
    display:block;
}
```

`#category2` becomes `.subcat`.

This implementation generalizes the behavior for each `select` that has class `subcat`.

#### EXAMPLE

http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/9/

*I'm not English, and right now I haven't time to correct my grammar errors, sorry. :( My Bad.*

Comment: Thanks, this is great, do you have an idea how to make a 3rd category, that also would be triggered by category1?

Comment: What if one of the values in Category 2 was common to more than 1 category 1 values . For example : if "Audio/Video" in Category 2 was a dependent value for both "Home Ware" and "Education" ? How can this be achieved ?

Comment: @Frogmouth You have a neat solution there but your latest Fiddle does not work in Apple Safari. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: @stavasknall :( I haven't an apple device right now for debug, but I try take a look at this. Have you some other detail about the problem?

Comment: No, not really. One thing could be that Apple follows standards strict and does not allow "rel=" in "<option>" tag?

Comment: OK. You can use `data-rel` instead of `rel`, I try to change fiddle.

Comment: I have notice that in my fiddle some `rel` are Capitalized but `value` aren't.
Maybe Safari is case sensitive in `rel` selection: Try with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/550/

Comment: @Frogmouth, Thanks! Data-rel did some effect. It now works on Safari Desktop but not on Safari Mobile. This is strange I must say. Any idea why?

Comment: @stavasknall - mmmmmh... murble murble... I need some time to check the possibilities. :/ Without the browser console is too difficult to find the problem.

Comment: @Frogmouth, Yeah, same here. I used a freind whos on Macbook and got him to try things out. According to him, Developer Console in Safari does not spit out any error about this issue. Maybe idea to start a fresh topic on SO so more devs can try it out?

Comment: Hi @stavasknall! I found the error, in some browser the `<option />` element can't be hide with css. My approch isn't cross browser. I work to a new solution.

Comment: @Frogmouth, that seems to be working! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Frogmouth Following your latest solution (update 03/2018), is there a way to reset the dependent list on a button click? I am trying to create a form where the users can add/remove fields. Right now, when they add a previously removed pair of dropdown lists, the second one is no longer dependent on the first one...

Comment: @MikeMichaels Hi! In this script I figure that the DOM doesn't change.
If you add/remove new options on category and/or subcategories you have to add/remove the same options inside the "optgroups" variable.

Comment: @MikeMichaels I can't help because I can't understand your use case...

Comment: @Frogmouth No worries, mate. I figured it out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MikeMichaels you are welcome. If you create a JS fiddler with you use case we can work together on it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basic example (just javascript, no jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select onChange="jsFunction()" id="selectOpt1">
          <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <select id="selectOpt2">
          <option value="1">FIRST</option>
        </select>
        <select id="selectOpt3">
          <option value="1">FIRST</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            function jsFunction(){
              var list1 = document.getElementById("selectOpt1");
              var myselect = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;
              var list2 = document.getElementById('selectOpt2');
              var list3 = document.getElementById('selectOpt3');
              for (i = 0; i < list2.options.length; i++) {
                list2.options[i] = null;
              }
              for (i = 0; i < list3.options.length; i++) {
                list3.options[i] = null;
              }
              if(myselect==="1"){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = "1";
                opt.innerHTML = "FIRST";
                list2.appendChild(opt);
                opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = "1";
                opt.innerHTML = "FIRST2";
                list3.appendChild(opt);
              }
              else{
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = "2";
                opt.innerHTML = "SECOND";
                list2.appendChild(opt);
                opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = "1";
                opt.innerHTML = "SECOND2";
                list3.appendChild(opt);
              }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something similar, but is it possible to make that when you select "1" it would show two boxes with "FIRST" and "FIRST2".

Comment: No problem, just make sure that you will writer nicer code. You can also use jQuery to make things more readable and simplier.