# Two Drop down list in HTML both depends each other

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I have two drop down list in my code say Employee Name and Employee Number.If user will select Employee Name then automatically Employee number will be populated and set on the field and vice versa for selection of Employee Number.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: have you tried anything? show us some code. else you'll get more down votes

Comment: There are tons of questions on stackoverflow that already answer this question. Try this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623225/javascript-dependent-drop-down-list

Comment: At your service, Provided you help yourself first :) by posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: share your effort, i mean code you have tried??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML is like this:

```
<body>

<select id="names">
  <option value="id_1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="id_2">Saab</option>
  <option value="id_3">Opel</option>
  <option value="id_4">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="ids">
  <option value="id_1">id_1</option>
  <option value="id_2">id_2</option>
  <option value="id_3">id_3</option>
  <option value="id_4">id_4</option>
</select>

</body>
```

javascript is:

```
$("#names").change(function(){
  $("#ids").val($(this).val());
});

$("#ids").change(function(){
  $("#names").val($(this).val());
});
```

Don't forget to include jQuery

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs3fn211/1/)

Comment: Thank You.. But all earlier people are misleading one.