# If specific value from dropdown selected show different dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

In my html webpage I have a dropdown menu, when the user picks a value from the drop down i would like to show a subsequent dropdown. e.g. dropdown 1 pick value 1 > show dropdown 2. Dropdown 1 pick value 2 > show dropdown 3

I think i am nearly there in my code below, I have my three dropdowns and only the first one shows at the start. However I think I need to specify to have an if statement to say if client 1 selected set the dropdown client 1 to show and if client 2 selected set the dropdown client 2 to show.

I have tried an `if` statement but I can't get it working. I'm expecting some sort of syntax error at the very least or what I am trying simply doesn't work in the way I have approached it.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("client");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (strUser.value == "Client 1");
elem.onchange = function() {
  var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("client1");
  hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none" : "block";
};
else
  elem.onchange = function() {
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("client2");
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none" : "block";
  };
```

```html
<select class="default" id="client" name="client">
  <option value="" selected>Select Client</option>
  <option value="1">Nike</option>
  <option value="2">Adidas</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id="Nike_group" name="Nike_group" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">Zoom</option>
  <option value="2">Vapour</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id=Adidas_style" name="adidas_style" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">Running</option>
  <option value="2">Football</option>
<option value="3">Rugby</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id=Adidas_rugby" name="adidas_rugby" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">England</option>
  <option value="2">France</option>
  <option value="3">Wales</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id=Adidas_football" name="adidas_football" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">Man UTD</option>
  <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
  <option value="3">Everton</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - it obviously does not work due to bracket issues

Comment: You've got some syntax errors in your JS that may be responsible for the issues you are seeing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to do this

I am looping to hide the other select(s)

Updated to look at the selected text and the start of the ID string

In newer browsers you can use `sel.id.startsWith(strUser)`

```js
document.getElementById("client").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var strUser = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".default")].forEach(sel => {
    if (sel.id !== "client") { // don't hide the main select
      sel.style.display = sel.id.indexOf(strUser) === 0 ? "block" : "none"
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<select class="default" id="client" name="client">
  <option value="" selected>Select Client</option>
  <option value="1">Nike</option>
  <option value="2">Adidas</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id="Nike_group" name="Nike_group" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">Zoom</option>
  <option value="2">Vapour</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id="Adidas_style" name="adidas_style" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">Running</option>
  <option value="2">Football</option>
  <option value="3">Rugby</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id="Adidas_rugby" name="adidas_rugby" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">England</option>
  <option value="2">France</option>
  <option value="3">Wales</option>
</select>

<select class="default" id="Adidas_football" name="adidas_rugby" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="1">Man UTD</option>
  <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
  <option value="3">Everton</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ahh yes great thats exactly what i was after. Can you explain how the JS decides which secondary drop down to use? In my actual code the values and drop downs are not as clear as client 1 client 2 so im wondering how i transfer your example into my code.

Comment: The statement that does that is `sel.id === "client" + strUser` which will find `"client"+"1"` or `"client"+"2"` depending on the value being 1 or 2. If you would elaborate on your actual names/IDs or classNames, I could help you better

Comment: I have edited to show how the names are different, i have also added additional dropdowns that would need to show if certain options are chosen. hopefully it is clear which additional drop downs would need to show based on the selected choice.

Comment: See update. I added missing quotes to the IDs

Comment: Thanks, i know im moving the goal posts somewhat and asking a lot but hoping to learn from your knowledge as much as i can here. The drop down appears when nike is selected which is correct however when adidas is selected all three subsequent drop downs appear when really i would need adidas_style to appear and if football is selected then show adidas_football and not adidas_rugby.

Comment: That would have been useful to know before I started. It is more and different code to have more cascades. Also your values suck. Why are the values not reflecting the dropdown you want? so have value="Adidas_style" instead of "1"

Comment: Sorry, if its to much dont worry i will see what else i can find to build on what you've done. I thought when i found how to do it once i could build it out myself. They suck because a lack of knowledge to be honest, you think it would be better to have the value reflect the title e.g. <option value="England">England</option>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202257/discussion-between-a-smith-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Yes, certainly. I can help you but it is starting to be more like custom scripting than just "answer a question" ;)

Comment: Haha. I wanted to find a cascading dropdown script for you and google had this as #1 result https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/65Q9L/

Comment: ahh amazing your a hero

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623225/javascript-dependent-drop-down-list/29624809