# Depended multi-selected boxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

The code I use is mostly from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29624809/9481131

**Ongoing code:**

**HTML**

```
        <label style="font-weight: bold">Choose the literary genres</label>

          <select name="genre" id="genre" multiple>
            <option value="all">All genres</option>
            <option value="classic">Classic</option>
            <option value="romance">Romance</option>
            <option value="sciencefiction">Science fiction</option>
          </select>

        <label style="font-weight: bold">Choose the books</label>
          <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="book" name="book" multiple>
            <option value>All books</option>
            <!-- Classic books -->
            <optgroup data-rel="classic">
              <option value="classic_book_1">classic book 1</option>
              <option value="classic_book_2">classic book 2</option>
              <option value="classic_book_3">classic book 3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- Romance books-->
            <optgroup data-rel="romance">
              <option value="romance_book_1">romance book 1</option>
              <option value="romance_book_2">romance book 2</option>
              <option value="romance_book_3">romance book 3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- Science fiction books-->
            <optgroup data-rel="sciencefiction">
              <option value="sciencefiction_book_1">science fiction book 1</option>
              <option value="sciencefiction_book_2">science fiction book 2</option>
              <option value="sciencefiction_book_3">science fiction book 3</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    
    var $cat = $("#genre"),
        $subcat = $("#book");
    
    var optgroups = {};
    
    $subcat.each(function(i,v){
        var $e = $(v);
        var _id = $e.attr("id");
            optgroups[_id] = {};
            $e.find("optgroup").each(function(){
        var _r = $(this).data("rel");
        $(this).find("option").addClass("is-dyn");
        optgroups[_id][_r] = $(this).html();
            });
    });
    $subcat.find("optgroup").remove();
    
    var _lastRel;
    $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        if(_lastRel === _rel) return true;
        _lastRel = _rel;
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        $subcat.find(".is-dyn").remove();
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.each(function(){
            var $el = $(this);
          var _id = $el.attr("id");
          $el.append(optgroups[_id][_rel]);
        });
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    });
    
});
</script>
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/53tL7jhf/

To summarize, I have two select boxes (with the possibility of multi-select in each box). The data from second select box depend on data selected in first box.

**What I want:**

1. Then "All genres" is selected in the first box, the  second box show all books.
   Like this:

```
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    | Choose the literary genres |  Choose the books  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |    All genres (SELECTED)   |      All books     |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |    classic book 1  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |    classic book 2  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |    classic book 3  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |    romance book 1  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |    romance book 2  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |    romance book 3  |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            | sci fiction book 1 |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            | sci fiction book 2 |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
    |                            |         etc.       |
    |----------------------------|--------------------|
```

2. Then more than one genre is selected in the first box, the second box show the books from all selected genres.
   Like this:

```
|----------------------------|--------------------|
| Choose the literary genres |  Choose the books  |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
|       Classic (SELECTED)   |      All books     |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
| Science fiction (SELECTED) |    classic book 1  |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
|                            |    classic book 2  |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
|                            |    classic book 3  |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
|                            | sci fiction book 1 |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
|                            | sci fiction book 2 |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
|                            | sci fiction book 3 |
|----------------------------|--------------------|
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As , you have use `mutliple` in your select-box so the value  returning is in `array` .If you will do `console.log($(this).val())` output coming is in (array) i.e :`[..]`.So , currently your code just take one value not other .Instead you can use `each` loop again to iterate that array value as well.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(function() {

  var $cat = $("#genre"),
    $subcat = $("#book");

  var optgroups = {};

  $subcat.each(function(i, v) {
    var $e = $(v);
    var _id = $e.attr("id");
    optgroups[_id] = {};
    $e.find("optgroup").each(function() {
      var _r = $(this).data("rel");
      $(this).find("option").addClass("is-dyn");
      optgroups[_id][_r] = $(this).html();
    });
  });
  $subcat.find("optgroup").remove();
  var _lastRel;
  $cat.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    if (_lastRel === _rel) return true;
    _lastRel = _rel;
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style", "");
    $subcat.val("");
    $subcat.find(".is-dyn").remove();
    if (!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled", true);
    $subcat.each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      var _id = $el.attr("id");
      //if arrray contains all option
      if (_rel.indexOf("all") > -1) {
      //loop though options
        $("#genre option").each(function() {
        //append options in other selects
          $el.append(optgroups[_id][$(this).val()]);
        })
      } else {
        //loop through values got from selctbox
        $(_rel).each(function(index, value) {
          $el.append(optgroups[_id][value]); //passs that value
        }) //close
      }

    });
    $subcat.prop("disabled", false);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="font-weight: bold">Choose the literary genres</label>

<select name="genre" id="genre" multiple>
  <option value="all">All genres</option>
  <option value="classic">Classic</option>
  <option value="romance">Romance</option>
  <option value="sciencefiction">Science fiction</option>
</select>

<label style="font-weight: bold">Choose the books</label>
<select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="book" name="book" multiple>
  <option value>All books</option>
  <!-- Home Ware -->
  <optgroup data-rel="classic">
    <option value="classic_book_1">classic book 1</option>
    <option value="classic_book_2">classic book 2</option>
    <option value="classic_book_3">classic book 3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <!-- Education -->
  <optgroup data-rel="romance">
    <option value="romance_book_1">romance book 1</option>
    <option value="romance_book_2">romance book 2</option>
    <option value="romance_book_3">romance book 3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <!-- Books -->
  <optgroup data-rel="sciencefiction">
    <option value="sciencefiction_book_1">science fiction book 1</option>
    <option value="sciencefiction_book_2">science fiction book 2</option>
    <option value="sciencefiction_book_3">science fiction book 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! It solves my second problem! Do you have any idea about first question? (show all books in the second box then "All genres" is selected in the first box). Is it even possible? Many thanks in advance!